# Does anyone know of a very simple jQuery dropdown menu with smooth fadeout (or slide-down)?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Does anyone know of a very simple jQuery dropdown menu plugin where the opacity goes down smoothly (or where the menu slides down smoothly)??

Answer (score 2):

here are 38 jquery dropdown menu's
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

Comment: Yup, pretty much the first result on Google for 'jQuery dropdown menu' =)